# Angular component not found when using ComponentModule

Tags: angular

Good afternoon,

I have developed a modal which is used on 2 pages a "search page" and an "article page".

I have created a Module for the component to allow it to be used on the 2 pages. On the search page it works fine. Adding the module to imports of the search page search.module.ts  allows it to work perfectly.

When taking the same approach on the "article page" its giving me:

```
NG0304: 'app-addtoplanner' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-addtoplanner' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-addtoplanner' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

in the console.

I can not see where these two are different.

Articles Module (not working):

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticlesRoutingModule } from './articles-routing';
import { ArticleCardModule } from './article-card/article-card.module';
import { ArticleMainComponent } from './article-main/article-main.component';
import { CheckNewComponent } from './check-new/check-new.component';
import { UserHistoryComponent } from './user-history/user-history.component';
import { UniquePipe } from '../../../services/pipes/UniquePipe';
import { SafePipeModule } from '../../../services/pipes/SafePipe.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AddToPlannerModule } from './../../planner/add-to-planner.module';
import { JwPaginationModule } from 'jw-angular-pagination';
import { IsEditor, IsStudent } from '../../../services/can-activate-guard.service';
import { ArticleHeaderBarModule } from './articles-header-bar/article-header-bar.module';
import { WikiConverter } from '../../../services/wiki-converter.service';
import { BsModalService, ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ArticlesRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    AddToPlannerModule,
    JwPaginationModule,
    SafePipeModule,
    ArticleCardModule,
    ArticleHeaderBarModule,
    ModalModule,

  ],
  declarations: [
    UniquePipe,
    ArticleMainComponent,
    CheckNewComponent,
    UserHistoryComponent,

  ],
  providers: [
    IsStudent,
    IsEditor,
    WikiConverter,
    BsModalService
  ]
})
export class ArticlesModule { }
```

Search Module (working):

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchComponent } from './search.component'
import { SearchRoutingModule } from './search-routing'
import { ModalModule, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { AddToPlannerModule } from './../../planner/add-to-planner.module'
import { CalendarModule, DateAdapter } from 'angular-calendar';
import { adapterFactory } from 'angular-calendar/date-adapters/date-fns';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from '@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SearchRoutingModule,
    ModalModule,
    AddToPlannerModule,
    OwlDateTimeModule,
    OwlNativeDateTimeModule,
     CalendarModule.forRoot({
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useFactory: adapterFactory,
    }),
  ],
  declarations: [
   SearchComponent,
  ],
  providers: [BsModalService]
})
export class SearchModule { }
```

The modal module:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AddToPlannerComponent } from './add-to-planner/add-to-planner.component';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from '@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker';
import { CalendarModule, DateAdapter } from 'angular-calendar';
import { adapterFactory } from 'angular-calendar/date-adapters/date-fns';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    OwlDateTimeModule,
    OwlNativeDateTimeModule,
     CalendarModule.forRoot({
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useFactory: adapterFactory,
    }),
  ],
  declarations: [
    AddToPlannerComponent
  ],
  exports:
  [
    AddToPlannerComponent,
  ]
})
export class AddToPlannerModule {}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

did you try import AddToPlannerModule to ArticlesModule,they are 2 different modules, you need to import

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't have compiled without these.

Comment: if you dont change the component selector might be app-add-to-planner .you probably already checked. It was just a reminder